# How to use NEST v6 to percolate

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-percolate

How do I use the percolator capabilities of ES to match an incoming document with my query?
my query is "biggest winner"

I'm using ES v6 and the same version of NEST lib.

this is my class

```
public class PercolatedQuery
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public QueryContainer Query { get; set; }
}
```

this is my setting

```
Uri node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200/");
    this.Settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .DefaultIndex("mytestIndex");
    this.Client = new ElasticClient(this.Settings);
    if (!this.Client.IndexExists("mytestIndex").Exists)
    {
        this.Client.CreateIndex("mytestIndex", c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .NumberOfShards(1)
                .NumberOfReplicas(0)
            )
            .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<PercolatedQuery>(mm => mm
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        // map the query field as a percolator type
                        .Percolator(pp => pp
                            .Name(n => n.Query)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            );
        this.Client.Alias(a => a
            .Add(add => add
                .Index("mytestIndex")
                .Alias("testAlias")
            ));
    }
```

Comment: where do you index a `PercolatedQuery`?

Comment: I don't know how to use that. I could not find any documentation that explains it from a to z

Comment: Does the percolate query documentation help? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-percolate-query.html

Comment: Thank you, that's helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to save the query, then I could search for a document

```
        PercolatedQuery documentQuery = new PercolatedQuery
        {
            Id = "PercolatedQuery",
            Query = new MatchQuery
            {
                Field = Infer.Field<PercolatedQuery>(entry => entry.Body),
                Query = "healthcare biggest"
            }
        };
        Client.Index(documentQuery,
           d => d.Index("mytestIndex").Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor));

        PercolatedQuery document1 = new PercolatedQuery { Body = "healthcare biggest winner" };
        Client.Search<PercolatedQuery>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .Percolate(p => p
                    .Field(f => f.Query)
                    .Document(document1)
                )
            )
            );
```